# How to use $cond in mongoDB without an else expression?

Tags: mongodb

I want to add the values of $site to a variable if site!= 'undefined', else I have to skip that document and move on to the next.

I used

`{$addToSet: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$site", 'undefined' ] }, then: "$site"}}}`

But it returns "Missing 'else' parameter to $cond"

and if I add an else statement

1) `{$addToSet: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$site", 'undefined' ] }, then: "$site", else: {} }}}`

it returns the value to the addset {Object Object}

2) `{$addToSet: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$site", 'undefined' ] }, then: "$site", else: null }}}`

it returns null to the set like ["sample1", "sample2", ]

3) `{$addToSet: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$site", 'undefined' ] }, then: "$site", else: "" }}}`

it returns null to the set like ["sample1", "sample2", "" ]

I don't want anything to be added to the set if it does not satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 3.6, you can use the [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) variable as the `ELSE` argument of a `$cond` operator to prevent anything from being added to the set if the condition fails.

[See here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#remove-example) for an example from Mongo Docs.

In your case, we can get it done with,

```
{
    $group: {
            //_id: <group-by-expression>
            // other fields (if any)..
            sites: {
                $addToSet: { 
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $ne: ["$site", 'undefined'] },
                        then: "$site",
                        else: "$$REMOVE"
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    $group: {
            //_id: <group-by-expression>
            // other fields (if any)..
            sites: {
                $addToSet: { 
                    $cond: [
                        { $ne: ["$site", 'undefined'] },
                        "$site",
                        "$$REMOVE"
                    ]
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add null on else brach(I used the simpliefied cond [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)):

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
            A: {
            $addToSet: {
                $cond: [{ $ne: ["$site", 'undefined'] }, "$site", null]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "A": {
            "$setDifferrence": ["$A", [null]]
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexandru Martin, Thanks for your Suggestion. But When I try your method i got "Unrecognized expression '$setDifferrence'".

Comment: @RichardJebasinghS he made a typo please refer document its working for me